# how to determine field type with serialize in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I want to send a serialized form through ajax, but I need to know which field is select, and which is text input, but not sure how I can work that.

```
$('#contact_filter_btn').click(function(){
form = $('#contact_filter').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax/contact-filter.php',
    data    : form,
    success : function(data) {
        $('#customers_table').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas on how you can determine if the field was text or select? I dont mind making alterations to the html if that will help somehow

Comment: share your html code

Comment: you can get all elements with `$('select')` and `$('input')` and use `$.each` for get data from those elements. then create JSON with those arrays and send it to URL

Comment: You can just add the type to every input name, like : `<select name="example1_select">`, `<input name="example2_text">`,... and then in your back-end split each name by `_` to retrieve the real name and the type of it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the easiest solution was just to change the names of the form fields. So I changes the names to `$type.'_'.$name`

This then allowed me to know what type it was, and I just strpos/substr them in php, to extra the type and remove that part from name?